# can't connect on application via correct port on docker

Tags: php, mysql, windows, docker, wsl-2

I am a begginer in docker and a I am trying to setup the simpler enviroment for a legacy application. I have this docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
    my_app:
        build: .
        network_mode: "host"
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
            - "8443:443"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
```

And I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install sockets pdo_mysql
RUN sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/public!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/log \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/log \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/www/log
```

I was expecting to connect in the application with the address http://localhost:8080, but it only works on the address http://localhost. I guess that this line `network_mode: "host"` must have something to do with it, but if I remove it I can't connect on the mysql that is on the host machine.

As I am running docker on Wsl2 with Debian, I don't have access to the address host.docker.internal, so I have to use the IP of the host machine as the mysql host in the connection string

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Network mode 'host' makes it so your container listens directly on a host port and your port mappings don't do anything.

To be able to access MySQL on your host from the container when running on a Docker bridge network, you need to add a hostname for the `host-gateway`. Then you can use that name to access the host. The usual name to use is `host.docker.internal`.

When we do that, your docker-compose file looks like this

```
services:
    my_app:
        build: .
        extra_hosts:
            - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
            - "8443:443"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www
```

When you do that, you should be able to access MySQL from the container using the hostname `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: I am getting the error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused, using the host.docker.internal. =/

Comment: That sounds like it does connect, but the database refuses the connection for some reason. I think your app is set up correctly, but your database isn't accepting the connection.